# what is the best way to get the diff between commit and branch

Tags: git, git-diff

what is the best way to get the diff between specific commit (on another branch) and origin of specific branch ?

I am using following :

```
git diff --name-only origin/branch1..$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

but it seems , it is unstable , sometime it gives the diff and sometime not.

basically, I am trying to automate the merge process using gitlab CI and for that i need to understand that before merge process start , I want to get the diff between commit and specific branch .

is the git diff command right ? any changes in the command you suggest ?

Comment: please have a look
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Comment: I red the docs , but still not clear

Comment: You'd have to be more specific. Show us a case where the "expected" diff isn't produced.

Comment: Have you tried this ```git diff --name-only origin/branch1 $CI_COMMIT_SHA```?

Comment: @Donat: dropping the two dots won't make any difference here provided `$CI_COMMIT_SHA` expands to something (as opposed to expanding to nothing at all, in which case the two dots *do* matter). Meanwhile (@OP) there's nothing wrong with your `git diff` here. Any issues you have here are due to the way the GitLab CI actually works, which isn't defined by Git, but only by GitLab.

Comment: the issue is , using above command, in the first iteration/run of the merge automation process, it gives the list of files which are different .  but in the second iteration/run, it does not give any diff. why so ?? 
I confirmed that , nothing has been merged in the target branch so diff has to be there . but in the second run, it simply says , no diff